# MVC Required attribute not working on client side consistantly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I cannot get the required field validation messages to appear every time I clear a field and click on another one. It will appear after I clear more than one field and after another type of validation message has occurred first, but not for when I just go into the form, clear a required field, and click on another field. Below is my RegisterBundles method in BundleConfigs which includes what I think are the correct bundles for jqueryval.

```
     public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {

        //other bundles...

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        //other bundles ...

    }
```

Here is what my _Layout.cshtml file looks like, it seems like I have all the script bundles rendered.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/xeditable")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootgrid")

</head>
<body>

    @*Other layout stuff...*@


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)


</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Model class which seems correct based on what I have researched.

```
public class ModelClass
    {
        //fields...

        public Decimal DecimalProperty{get; set;}

        [Required(ErrorMessage="REQUIRED!")]
        public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage="REQUIRED!")]
        public DateTime OtherDateProperty { get; set; }

         //Other properties not associated with visible form fields..
    }
```

Finally, here is my view which has the label, textbox, and validation message components in a form.

```
    @model ModelClass


        @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { id = Model.ID}, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DecimalProperty, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DecimalProperty, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DecimalProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DateProperty, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateProperty, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OtherDateProperty, "Other Date", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OtherDateProperty, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OtherDateProperty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Please note that I am somewhat new at MVC and I tried to take out everything which I did not deem necessary for understanding.

Comment: DateTime is a value type then ASP.NEt MVC model binder will give a default value when the user doesn't set it. To make it work you need to make your required properties nullabel by using `Nullable<DateTime>`instead of `DateTime`.

Comment: On your view, you have code for Validation for Decimal Property, but you don't have the Data Annotation to say that it is required on the model.  It should be the same as the other TextBoxes.

Comment: @CodeNotFound, That's not true. A `DateTime` property cannot be `null` and if the textbox is cleared (resulting in a `null` value), a  validation error will be displayed (and `ModelState` will be invalid when the form is submitted)

Answer (score 0):

The comment section couldn't take everything.  Here's what you miss:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage="REQUIRED!")]
    public Decimal DecimalProperty{get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="REQUIRED!")]
    public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage="REQUIRED!")]
    public DateTime OtherDateProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: A `[Required]` attribute is not required at all. Both `DateTime` and `Decimal` must have a value (they cannot be `null`). The only reason for adding the attribute is to display a custom error message rather than the default error message (which would be _"The field DecimalProperty is required"_